# PutS only displaying one character on TI-84 Plus Silver edition

Tags: z80

I have recently discovered that my TI-84 plus silver edition can be programmed in hex. I have been messing around with it but have had a few bugs. Whenever I try to make a bcall to PutS it only prints one character and moves on. If I add a second PutS command it puts the second letter down and to the right by one. My current code is:

```
AsmPrgm
219D9D
EFD9481C
C9
48692100
```

Comment: This works fine (prints Hi!) on my calculator (TI-84+ black)

Comment: Strange, it still does not work for me. I have an emulator I will try it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necro reply: It seems like you are using one of the new Math Print OSes. Because of the "pretty print" math, TI had to change how strings are printed to the screen. Unfortunately, they broke older functions that as _PutS. One way to get around it is to just put your calc into Classic mode. This disables math print, so printing characters to the homescreen will work as expected.

Go to [Mode],[down] 8 times, [right], [Enter]

Answer (score 0):

It works on my 84+ too. There is nothing wrong with this program.
Possible solutions:

1. Check if you typed in the hexadecimal correctly.
2. Perhaps you are using a different OS version that has the bcall at a different location in memory. My os version is 2.43 (no mathprint)

Good luck!

Comment: I am running 2.55MP, do you know where I could find the bcall address

Comment: The bcall for _puts is 4501. You used _putsm. I am not sure if that works in your os version. I can try it using another calc I got with that os version.