# Only printing H for a “Hello World!” program in TI 84+ CE Assembly

Tags: assembly, hex, opcode, texas-instruments

For whatever reason, I’ve decided I want to learn to program my TI 84+ CE in Assembly using only the hex codes. Don’t ask me why.

Anyway, I’ve followed the tutorial ["Hello, World!" in Hex codes for TI-84+CE](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/forum/t-1776451/hello-world-in-hex-codes-for-ti-84-ce).

However, instead of printing `Hello World!`, it prints an `H`. The output looks like this:

[image: TI's code]

Here’s the code:

```
Asm84CEPrgm
218EA8D1
CDC00702
CDF00702
C9
48656C6C6F2C20776F726C642100
```

I can’t figure out why it only prints an `H` and I hope someone could help.

Edit: I think I found a question addressing the same issue. It seems to be a problem with Mathprint. [PutS only displaying one character on TI-84 Plus Silver edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141829/puts-only-displaying-one-character-on-ti-84-plus-silver-edition)

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: The code was in the tutorial I linked, but I included it anyway.

Comment: Certainly looks like it should work assuming you are really calling `_PutS` and not something like `_PutChar`. Does it always print the first letter? Try changing the `48` to something else to test.

Comment: The tutorial says it’s _PutS and I don’t know anyway to confirm that, so I’m assuming it’s right. If I change it to 58, it prints X.

Comment: Try to find a real tutorial for "real" asm programming the Ti-84. The tutorial you posted is pointless, and you will not get far with this. It's like "driving bicycle with closed eyes", you can do it for 2 meters straight, but it will not bring you anywhere

Comment: This was the best I could find. I found a good tutorial for the regular TI 83/84, but that isn’t compatible with the TI 84+ CE. Once I get started, I’ll probably follow the first tutorial and just use a table to convert to the right hexcodes.

Comment: It's also suspicious that the cursor is at the top. What happens if you remove the second call (the `CDF00702`)?

Comment: _"This was the best I could find."_ How about https://ez80.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/intro.html

Comment: That doesn't use hex codes

Comment: @Jester If I remove the second call, it outputs this: http://imgur.com/shymEOl

Comment: Also, editing the program to have CDC00702 twice results in it printing the H and the e. I think it’s noteworthy that calling the program a second time without clearing the screen results in the output being printed on the far right of the screen.

Comment: Using vPutS or PutPS works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with Mathprint messing up the formatting. The solution is to go into the mode settings and change it from Mathprint to Classic.

Here's a similar question addressing the same topic: [PutS only displaying one character on TI-84 Plus Silver edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141829/puts-only-displaying-one-character-on-ti-84-plus-silver-edition)